# Confusion on Big $O$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am so confused on the intuitive idea behind Big $O$ notation.

$f(x)=O(g(x))$ iff there is a constant $C>0$ such that for large $x, |f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|$ and I have seen that in many places that this means "$f$ grows as fast as or faster than $g$ for large $x$."

But if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$, we have $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$ for large $x$ and hence $f(x)=O(g(x))$ in this case. However, $f$ does not grow faster than $g$.

Can somebody please help me to resolve this?

Edit: Indeed I need the exact intuitive idea.. Not just definitions..

Comment: You have them back to front, $f = O(g(x))$ means that $g$ grows faster than $f$.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted. It means that if $f$ grows faster than $g$, its by at most a constant factor. There is another interpretation:
$$f=O(g) \iff \lim \ \dfrac{f}{g} < \infty$$

Comment: @James: No. I don't think so.

Comment: Yes you have. Look at the definition: ... $|f(x)| \leq C |g(x)|$, $g$ is on "big side" of the inequality, so $g$ is the big thing. Also, notice that, say, $x$ is $O(x^2)$ and $O(x^3)$ and $O(2^x)$ etc, and the growth rates are increasing here!

Comment: $f(x) = O(g(x))$ does not mean that $f$ grows faster than $g$ or that $g$ grows faster than $f$.  Note that $f(x) = O(f(x))$ holds, and that even if $f\ne g$, as you observed, one can have both $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and $g(x) = O(f(x))$.  I don't know of a  simple description of the meaning of $O()$ other than to say that    $f(x) = O(g(x))$ means that for large enough $x$,  $f$ is bounded above by a constant multiple of $g$.  To get a better understanding, you need to do some problems with it and see a lot of examples.

Comment: @James: What if $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=2x$? Then $f(x)\leq 2g(x)$. Does $g$ grows faster than $f$?

Comment: @MJD: If it does not have a simple meaning, then how people use it in Computer Science such as for complexity of algorithms?

Comment: Because it's really useful!  Things don't have to be simple to be useful; they have to capture some essential feature of the problem. The "sufficiently large" captures the fact that you don't care how the algorithm performs on small inputs (where any algorithm will be fast) and the "constant factor" captures the fact that you don't care about the relative times of basic operations, such as whether a multiplication takes as long as seven additions or only three.

Comment: In that example, notice that both $f = O(g)$ and $g = O(f)$ so things get a stickier. The definition doesn't perfectly capture the notion of growth rate as you don't care about small $x$ or a multiple of a constant. However, you asked for the "intuitive idea" and the one you suggested '$f$ grows as fast as or faster than $g$ for large $x$' has things back to front.

Comment: Ok then as I undestand, if we have only $f=O(g)$, then $g$ grows as fast as or faster than $f$, and if we have both $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$, there is no simple intuitive idea.. Am I correct?

Comment: Well, kinda. It isn't the best mathematical practice to begin learning about something with an intuition that you know isn't actually correct: You should just stick to the definition. I try to think about it this way. CS is, basically, a branch of applied math. Because it is applied, we frequently don't care about "negligible differences". Now, these differences are different in different contexts, but, in the context of algorithm run time analysis, we don't care about the algorithms performance on small inputs, and, we don't care about multiplication by a scalar...

Comment: So $f = O(g)$ is saying (very roughly, and upto our agreement that we don't care about small $x$ or multiplication by $c$) that $f(x) \leq g(x)$. Then $f = O(g)$ and $g = O(f)$ is saying $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq f(x)$, so, these functions $f$ and $g$ aren't different *upto our agreement about scalars and $c$*. Cool?

Answer (score 1):

Big O is up to a constant domination. If $f(x) = x, g(x) = 2x$, then $5*f(x) \geq g(x)$ for large $x$ (in fact, every $x>0$, but this is only an asymptotic statement with big O), for example. So, $g(x) = O(f(x))$. Similarly, $1 * g(x) \geq f(x)$ for large $x$ so we also have $f(x) = O(g(x))$.

In this case, we say $f(x) = \Theta(g(x))$.

Comment: I need the correct intuitive idea....